# Thread.Sleep() only raises Exception on Linux

Tags: java, linux, exception, interrupted-exception

I have a piece of code, which only raises exception when deployed on Linux. It runs fine on Windows and Unix.

```
   try {

        // Sleeping for 90 secs
        Thread.sleep(90000);
   }
   catch (InterruptedException ex) {

    System.out.println("Exception Raised !!");

   }
 }
```

This piece of code outputs Exception Raised only when deployed onto Linux. Can this be a File permissions issue ?

Java Version !!

java version "1.7.0_55"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_55-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.55-b03, mixed mode)

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the exception message?

Comment: What version of Java? I just ran it without exception using Java 8 on my Linux machine. Add `ex.printStackTrace()` to your `catch`, you're swallowing the `Exception`.

Comment: Thanks Elliott, I'll confirm the Java version and keep posted !!

Comment: java version "1.7.0_55"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_55-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.55-b03, mixed mode)